# How do I undo to commits and pushes to github?

Tags: git, github

I made some changes on my github site and its not working after I pushed it so I made so changes n try to push again.. still not workin.. so how can I rollback my github site two commits and to pushes ago>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git push -f
```

The best advice would be to learn about the `git reflog` and then you could just reset directly to the commit SHA desired.

Comment: I dont know why I had to do the first line two times but it woked...

Comment: well I thought you said you needed to "undo" 2 commits. If it was really 4 then you whould have needed to do it twice or you could have just done `git reset --hard HEAD~4`

really tho, learn about the `git reflog` and you could have just reset directly to the sha

Comment: @JMSAZ2013 , you can read more about reset here http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html . Also, you can read progit book - it explains lot more about git. http://git-scm.com/book

Answer (score 0):

Use `git revert sha1` command. Get the `sha1` by running `git log`. Push after you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You would rollback your local machine, then force a push to github...  I'd recommend creating a copy of what you have since the rollback will be destructive.  This also assumes the branch you want to rollback is `master`:

```
git checkout -b backup_branch # create backup branch
git checkout master # checkout branch to rollback
git reset --hard HEAD~2 # reset to 2 revisions before the HEAD
git push --force origin master # force push to github
```